# Analytic solution for $x = \frac{n}{1 + e^{-ax + t}}$ i.e. When is the output of a parametrised logistic function equal to the input?

Tags: machine-learning

I would like to know when is the input to a parametrised logistic function (the right hand side) equal to its output.

I've been trying to solve the following equation:

$$x = \frac{n}{1 + e^{-ax + t}}$$

Is it possible to solve this equation analytically?

Thank you for any answers or ideas!

Comment: just for fun but with the tanh function, they can be equal at $x=0$, right?

Comment: yes, they're very similar aren't they - do you mea maybe looking at $x = tanh(x)$?